# emacs --no-window-system customization

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, ubuntu-12.04, colors

I'm using

```
emacs -nw
```

as my editor on my Ubuntu 12.04 system.

However, the **--no-window-system** does not use the colors of the terminal.

**QUESTION**

How could I change the default colors of the *emacs -nw*?

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways to change the colors used by emacs.

1. If you want a syntax coloring with the terminal colors, the link below offers some settings for the terminal to enable it
   [Emacs Syntax Highlighting in No Window Mode](http://www.daniweb.com/hardware-and-software/linux-and-unix/threads/70899/emacs-syntax-highlighting-in-no-window-mode)
2. Otherwise, you can use color themes, [Color Themes](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorTheme). (It works for emacs 23).
3. Change it by hand, as explained here : [Change Emacs syntax highlighting colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076503/change-emacs-syntax-highlighting-colors).